# SAP Spartacus Unhandled Promise rejection: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ApplicationModule

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Hi I'm having an issue with using Spartacus 4.3 in zone.js. Build is successful but I cannot view my local since it has an issue with Unhandled Promise rejection: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ApplicationModule. Please advise

Heres what's inside my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^12.0.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^7.0.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^12.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^12.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^12.1.0",
    "@spartacus/asm": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/assets": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/cart": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/checkout": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/core": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/order": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/product": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/smartedit": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/storefinder": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/storefront": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/styles": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/tracking": "~4.3.8",
    "@spartacus/user": "~4.3.8",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "i18next": "^20.2.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.2.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^10.1.0",
    "@spartacus/setup": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.2",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/core": "^14.0.1",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/ui-material": "^14.0.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "country-flag-icons": "^1.1.1",
    "fastify": "^2.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "material-dynamic-table": "^9.4.0",
    "moment-jdateformatparser": "^1.2.1",
    "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-sticky-kit": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-device-detector": "1.4.6",
    "ngx-image-zoom": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.4.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.1.13",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.18",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.16",
    "@spartacus/schematics": "4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "element-closest-polyfill": "1.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.0",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^1.1.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^10.1.0"
  },
```

is this related to this? https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/11016

[image]

Comment: Are you able to also reproduce it in the out of the box Spartacus 4.3? (btw. did you make sure to upgrade to the latest patch 4.3.x?). Did the same code work for you in previous versions of Spartacus (if yes, which one)?

Comment: The error cause looks strange - it says the Angular's `Router` is not provided... Did  you make any customizations around Anuglar's Router module, or Spartacus AppRoutingModule? https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/4.3.8/projects/storefrontlib/router/app-routing.module.ts#L7-L25

Answer (score 0):

Hi was able to fixed the issue due to router module. Some modules requred in router module was not present.